# Selenium, what exactly is a xpath

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, xpath

I'm using selenium for  the first time and to locate a WebElement i use the selenium IDE. The id or the name of the WebElement dynamicaly loaded by a xml file, so to build my script i use the xpath of the WebElement, it seems to be constant.
But i want to know what exactly the xpath was. I have some idea but i'm not sure. By exemple to locate a specific link i will have :

```
//li[6]/ul/li[3]/a
```

I understand it as follow :
The first "a" tag contained in the third li of the ul contained in the sixth li of the page.
Am i wrong ?

Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath

Comment: refer this for understanding http://searchsoa.techtarget.com/definition/XPath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li>
            <a>It will find this one</a>
        </li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
```

Xpath cheat cheets:

http://scraping.pro/res/xpath-cheat/xpath_css_dom_recipes.pdf

http://scraping.pro/res/xpath-cheat/xpath_css_dom_ref.pdf